# Unknown app indicator

Tags: 18.04, indicator

[image]

Can someone tell me what the far left icon means and how to remove it? I've disabled network-manager, and use WICD on ubuntu 18.04 LTS. I'm also experiencing wifi drop outs, so I want to understand my system better.

There's a list of indicators here: https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/ubuntu-help/status-icons.html.en but I cannot find the one in question.

Comment: It's a Network icon. It means your network is indeterminate...which matches your description.

Comment: @user535733 Do you know how to get rid of it?

Comment: That's a completely different question.

Comment: @user535733 I've know added it ;P